# Logging statement progress in VBA - a "trace"

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, trace

I am not a very experienced programmer, but use VBA a lot for general purposes in conjunction with Excel.
I have a recent problem with my VBA code which I can't understand. Short of placing Debug.Print statements after every line of code, I wondered if there is a simple "Trace" facility that could tracks the execution of every statement?
The output would resemble something like this:

"Called procedure X

Within X, Called procedure Y
Executed line A, line B, line C of procedure Y
(showing perhaps the value of a particular variable at every stage)
exitted procedure Y, returning to X
value of variable is such and such
Exitted procedure X"

etc.

Comment: I appreciate the help, below from nodoubt and jkieters thankyou. However, I am already familiar with debugging, breaking the code and displaying the call stack, and immediate window. I feel I did not phrase my question correctly. What I need is a kind of continuous output (for every statement the processing runs through) so that I can follow where the code went AFTER it has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can run the code line after line by using the key F8 in your keyboard.

   example if you have three line of code:

- line 1
- line 2
- line 3

By pressing the F8 key, the system will walk you through line after line of code. After the line 1 is executed the system wait for you to press F8 to execute the line 2 and so on.

2. In VBA, you can also set a breakpoint before running the code.

[image: refer the image to see how to set dot]

That is: You can click on the left of the line that you want to stop and execute when you want, and that click makes a dot.

When you start running the code the system waits at the dotted line for you to execute manually that is you can continue executing the code by pressing F8 key in the keyboard.

Comment: While you are debugging using the method shown here, click View, Locals Window to keep tabs on values of your variables.

Comment: I appreciate the help, thankyou. However, I am already familiar with debugging, breaking the code and displaying the call stack, and immediate window. I feel I did not phrase my question correctly. What I need is a kind of continuous output (for every statement the processing runs through) so that I can follow where the code went AFTER it has gone wrong.